# Why can you set the stack size on CUDA GPU devices with compute capability 2.0+ only?

Tags: cuda

I guess I have a couple questions related to the call stack, but my main one would be,

- "Why can you set the stack size on devices with compute capability 2.0+ only?"
- Also, why can I only view the call stack using nvidia Nsight for devices with compute capability 2.0 and above only? 
  What's so special about 2.0+ devices that allows them to do this, but not 1.x devices?

I know this is a pretty broad question, but any insight into the above questions' answers or even information on the stack call on CUDA devices in general would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older 1.x devices can't implement a stack, so it doesn't make sense to allow it. At least one reason 2.0+ devices are able to implement a stack is because they have instructions which take generic pointers as operands. That means the compiler doesn't need to track the type (shared, local, or global) of each pointer as it flows through the program -- the hardware can just figure it out. This makes it possible to implement separate compilation (with a stack and ABI) because the compiler doesn't need visibility into the entire program in order to track the type of each and every pointer.

Comment: Insightful! And why would you want to be able to change the size of the stack? Is it so that you can allocate more local variables and function calls on the stack? Where does this space get taken from?

Comment: The size of the stack controls the depth of function calls and recursion. The larger the stack, the deeper the recursion.